# How to print multiple strings in columns

Tags: python, list, loops, printing

I'm trying to get two values or a set of strings in separate columns.
The code below will randomize two letters from the list. The issue I'm having with this is that they keep returning in vertical and I would like to print them next to each other. I tried several ways and none of them work. They either print them the same way as the below output or just print every character individually even the `╔`, `\n`, etc.

```
import random

letters = {'A', 'B', 'C'}
letter = list(letters)

for _ in range(2):
    random_letter = random.choice(letter)
    print(" ╔═══╗\n", f"║ {random_letter} ║\n", "╚═══╝", end='')
```

The method above returns this,

```
╔═══╗
║ A ║
╚═══╝╔═══╗
║ C ║
╚═══╝
```

This other method returns it like this,

```
print("╔═══╗", f"║ {random_letter} ║", "╚═══╝", end='')


╔═══╗ ║ A ║ ╚═══╝╔═══╗ ║ C ║ ╚═══╝
```

I would like it to return like this,

```
╔═══╗╔═══╗
║ A ║║ C ║
╚═══╝╚═══╝
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import random

letters = {'A', 'B', 'C'}
letter = list(letters)

def print_random_letter_boxes(num_letters = 2):
    print("".join(["╔═══╗" for _ in range(num_letters)]))
    print("".join([f"║ {random.choice(letter)} ║" for _ in range(num_letters)]))
    print("".join(["╚═══╝" for _ in range(num_letters)]))

print_random_letter_boxes()
```

Comment: It is a nice way of printing it, but not what I want. It returns the items inside a ` `.

Comment: @arm65: Works for fine me. What exactly do you mean inside a ` `?

Comment: Never mind, I didn't realize it was a function and just print it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize how many boxes you want in a variable which is ***hmb*** here:

```
import random

letters = {'A', 'B', 'C'}
letter = list(letters)
v = False # a bool to check if i have printed upper portions of the boxes
hmb = 2 # this is the "how many boxes" variable
for _ in range(hmb):
    random_letter = random.choice(letter)
    if not v:
        print("╔═══╗"*hmb)
        v = True # it means all upper portion printed
    if v:
        print("║",random_letter,"║",end="")
    if _ == hmb-1: # the lower part of the boxes will only be printed if its the last time of the loop
        print()
        print("╚═══╝"*hmb)
```